# FB Init - reloadIfSessionStateChanged is not working

Tags: facebook

Can some one please tell me what is wrong with below code?  After I login it doesn't do anything: neither reloading the page nor setting the login FB cookies.

It's simple code but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">       
   FB.init(FB_API_KEY, "xd_receiver.htm",{"reloadIfSessionStateChanged":true});
</script>

<a href='#' onclick='FB.Connect.requireSession(); return false;'> <img id='fb_login_image' src='fblogin.jpg' alt='Connect' /> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your application in "Connect" tab in [www.facebook.com/developers/yourapp?](http://www.facebook.com/developers/yourapp?)